# c# doing rowimport only on specific columns

Tags: c#, datatable

```
        foreach (DataRow row in orderedTable.Rows)
        {
            dttemp.ImportRow(row);
        }
```

i would like to import only the first and second columns. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
dttemp.Rows.Add(new object[] { row[0], row[1] });
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataTable.ImportRow(System.Data.DataRow)' has some invalid arguments C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\GenerateWorklists\GenerateWorklists\Form1.cs 654 17 GenerateWorklists

Comment: That would be because you didn't change ImportRow to Rows.Add

Comment: ! beautiful thank you. wh8at is the reason it doenst work with importrow?

Comment: ImportRow just takes an existing DataRow and jams it into another DataTable with the same schema.  The Rows.Add method creates a new DataRow with a list of supplied values and matches it up to the schema of the other DataTable (dttemp in your case).